# Integrating Marketing Cloud with Sales/Service Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Currently, we have our Marketing Cloud org connected to Sales Cloud org using Marketing Cloud Connect and everything seems to be working fine. However, there is a new requirement where we also need to pull in data from Service Cloud to Marketing Cloud. Does that mean I need to separately integrate my Marketing Cloud org with the Service Cloud org ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your requirement: "pull in data from Service Cloud to Marketing Cloud" you already have the objects mirrored in synced DEs. What more data do you need?

Comment: Yes, but those objects are from Sales Cloud. In order to mirror objects from Service Cloud, don't I need to synchronize Marketing Cloud separately with Service Cloud ? Pardon me as I am new to Sales/Service Cloud.

Comment: If these are two separate orgs, you indeed need to use Multi-Org connector as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5)